# Why do we use different prepositions in "no point in" and "no reason to"?

Tags: prepositions

I am wondering why in "There's no point **in** doing that" we use the preposition *in* but in "There's no reason **to** do that" we use the preposition *to*?

Comment: Different words have different usage rules. You can discover them in the usage examples in EFL dictionaries like the Macmillan [link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/). Another way of saying this is "Because that's the way we say it."

Comment: Is there any point _to_ this question?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that in this case *to* is not a preposition—it's an infinitive marker, which tells you that the immediately following verb is to be construed as an infinitive.

However, with the gerund (*doing* in your example) or any other nominal you may use *either* preposition: *There's no point **in** flying* = *There's no point **to** flying.* **in** is far more usual, but **to** is unremarkable.

**EDIT**
OP asks how we may know that *to* is an infinitive marker in *no reason to do that*.

First, any preposition requires a nominal—a noun, a pronoun, a gerund, or a noun phrase—as its object.

Consider then the following sentences. (In order to keep the constructions parallel I start with instances of prepositional *to* with *reason*, a usage which is uncommon today, but acceptable.)

> *There's no reason **to that**.*  ...  *that* is a pronoun, the object of the preposition *to*, so we can separate it from *to* and move it to the head of a sentence and say ***That*** is irrational.
>
> *There's no reason **to doing that**.*  ...  *doing* is a nominal, a gerund, and *doing that* is a nominal phrase—again, it's the object of the preposition *to*, so we can say ***Doing that*** is irrational.

But:

> *There's no reason **to do that**.*  ...  The bare infinitive form *do*, and the phrase *do that*, cannot be employed nominally; we cannot parse *do that* as the object of the preposition *to* and say ****Do that*** is irrational, which is meaningless.

We must parse *to* as an infinitive marker on *do* and employ the two together to produce the acceptable sentence ***To do that*** is irrational.

Comment: But they have vastly different meanings:  "*no point* **in** *flying*" means "there's nothing to be gained by using an aircraft to get you to your destination" while "*no point* **to** *flying*" means that flying is an activity with no particular goal.

Comment: Could you explain why 'to' in "There's no reason to do that" is an infinitive marker but in "There's no point to flying" it's a preposition ?

Comment: @Jim  I can't agree. There may be authorities somewhere who say that the different prepositions *should* distinguish different meanings, but I see no evidence that they actually do so in practice.  See J.R.'s comment to the original question.

Comment: @JatSing  I hope my edit provides the explanation you want.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you for your edited answer but the most thing I am concerning is that why `to` is used as a different role in those 2 sentences ? Can we say "There's no point to do that" or "There's no reason to doing that". Or the answer really is just like what Bill Franke said, that's the habit of native speakers ?

Comment: @JatSing   *reason* takes **either** a prepositional phrase (*to NOMINAL*) **or** a marked infinitive (*to VERB*) as its complement. *point* takes **only** the prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 1):

This question conflates two separate distinctions, that need to be addressed separately to gain any clarity:

- **Point** (purpose or teleology) vs **Reason** (motivation or justification)
- **in doing** (the gerund form of the verb) vs **to do** (the infinitive form)

A.  *There's no `point` **in doing** this* --- *There's no `reason` **for doing** this.*

The nouns *point* and *reason* produce the different prepositions *in* and *for*.  I'd submit that, on the one hand, the *point* (end purpose) is presumed to be found contained within the doing of something, in the sense that it (the end purpose) should emerge as a result of the act of doing.  On the other hand, the *reason* (motivation) is something that comes from you, not from the doing itself, but which you hold out *for* the act of doing.

B.  *There's no reason `in doing` this* --- *There's no reason `to do` this*

As StoneyB's answer points out, the forms of the verb here imply a subtle semantic difference.  (Note that I'm deliberately using *reason* in both sentences here, in order to isolate the difference produced by the verb forms.)  On the one hand, the gerund form *doing* of the verb, combined with the preposition *in*, implies a present tense, as if the doing were underway.  The word *reason* in this context takes on the meaning of *sense*, as in, there is *no sense*, no sound thought contained in the doing of this.

On the other hand, the infinitive *to do* connotes a future tense (it denotes atemporal, but we read it as a doing yet to come); and *reason* in this context again takes on the meaning of motivation or justification.  *There's no justification for undertaking the doing of this.*

This brings me back to *for doing*, which, in combining the gerund form of the verb *doing* with the preposition *for* (which, remember, I also identified as connoting justification), implies a judgement for a doing that is already underway (or on the precipice): *there's no reason for doing this* is a disapproving judgement after-the-fact.